# Is java's setIfAbsent(K,V, ExpiryTimeout) in redis atomic?

Tags: java, redis, spring-data-redis

According to the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/core/ValueOperations.html#setIfAbsent-K-V-), spring data redis's `setIfAbsent(K, V)` uses `setNX` command. However, `setIfAbsent(K, V, Expiry timeout)` [seems to use](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/core/ValueOperations.html#setIfAbsent-K-V-java.time.Duration-) `set` command, instead of `setNX`. Does it mean that having to set timeout on a key,value makes it not atomic?

In my use case, I want to set TTL for each row and I'm trying to understand how redis would behave if two threads (or application instances) call `setIfAbsent(K,V, sometimeoutinminutes)` at the same time? Does only one request update the key (`setNX` behavior) or both update the key?

Looking at the [implementation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis/blob/e2e68aa57200505e89b5a30006865cb0b488e6e2/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/redis/core/DefaultValueOperations.java#L285), I can see that both have slightly different code paths, so which makes me wonder if the latter is really atomic.

My code looks like this:

```
@Bean
public RedisTemplate<?, ?> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    RedisTemplate<?, ?> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
    template.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);

    return template;
}

code that updates:

//try to get value for a given key from redis.
String value = redisTemplate.opsForValue().get(key);

//if present, return value to the caller.
if (value != null) {
  return value;
}

//if not, fetch value from remote.
value = makeNetworkCallToGetValue(key);
if (value != null) {
    // update redis. what happens if 2 threads/application instances call this at the same time?
    redisTemplate.opsForValue().setIfAbsent(key, value, Duration.ofMinutes(1));
}

return value;
```

Library version: spring-data-redis:2.6.4

Comment: @bhusan do you got the answer? or having alternative solution?

Comment: No, I didn't get an answer nor find an alternative solution. I skipped using this functionality for now.

Answer (score 2):

The 3- and 4-param `setIfAbsent()` overloads pass an arg `SetOption.ifAbsent()` to `connection.set()`. This appears to populate `NX` onto the redis `SET` command similarly to what `connection.setNX()` would do. I'm guessing they wanted to refactor to this approach to reduce the number of method overloads that are needed to support all combinations of options and arguments to `SET`.

`SetOption.ifAbsent()`:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis/blob/2.6.4/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/redis/core/DefaultValueOperations.java#L379

`LettuceConverters.toSetArgs(expiration, option)`:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis/blob/2.6.4/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/redis/connection/lettuce/LettuceStringCommands.java#L139

`args.nx()`:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis/blob/2.6.4/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/redis/connection/lettuce/LettuceConverters.java#L800

Answer (score 0):

As of spring boot 3.1.1, using jedis and lettuce, the actual command (with a timeout of 30 seconds) sent to redis  is:

"SET" "key" "value" "NX" "EX" "30"